# How to check if a character is in an 2d array and then print the corresponding values

Tags: python, arrays, char

I want to create a program that asks the user for a word. Gives each character in the alphabet a number and then prints out the number for each character in the word they have guessed.

I have seemed to confuse myself with the code I have created. Any advice?

```
   T2 = [["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"],
     ["_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_",]]
for i in range(0,26,1):
    T2[1][i] = list2[i]
list2 = []
for i in range(100):
    r = random.randint(0,26)
    if r not in list2: list2.append(r) 

list3 = []
for i in range(26):
    r = random.randint(0,5)
    if r not in list3: list3.append(r) 

for i in range(0,26,1):
    T2[1][i] = list2[i]

for r in T2:
    for c in r:
        print(c,end = " ")
    print()

guesses = ''
wordtoprint=""
word = input("What is the secret word? ").lower().strip()

for char in word:
    if char in T2[0]:
        char = T2[][i]
        wordtoprint=wordtoprint+char+" "
print(wordtoprint)
```

i would like to see an output of 
 if the user inputted the word  hello
output the output would be the  numbers those letters correspond with. 
ie 23 4 8 8 13

Comment: what is list2 ?

Comment: Can you please add sample input and expected output.

Comment: list 2 is a list contain all of the random numbers between 0,26 for each letter in the alpbet

Comment: Is that complete code? It seems to be missing initialization of list2.

Comment: i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I think that a dictionary will help you a lot. Instead of...

```
T2 = [["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"],
       ["_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_",]]

for i in range(0,26,1):
    T2[1][i] = list2[i]
```

Use something like that...

```
import string

all_letters = enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1)

pairs = []
for pair in all_letters:
    pairs.append( pair[::-1] )

T2 = dict(pairs)
```

Now you can map each letter to a number easily.